# Ask Question page "Tips to improve question" link overflows sidebar, has incorrect formatting, has incorrect URL on Math SE

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, sidebar

Poking around on the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com), I got a notice saying I should improve my question title, and the links to the resources not only had incorrect formatting but also flowed over the sidebar:

[image]

The link also needs to be `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com` instead of `http://meta.math` to avoid certificate errors, but it redirects to the correct one for me.

Can we please fix this?

Comment: The link should also start with `https://math.meta` instead of `http://meta.math` to avoid HTTPS certificate errors.

Comment: The meta.math URL likely dates back to when that was the actual URL (it was only switched around relatively recently); in any case, I don't think that's applicable to the rest of the network